# how to open link in a new tab in the messenger bot platform

Tags: node.js, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

there's 2 types of postback buttons :-> "url" and the normal postback

is there anyway to use the normal postback for opening a url

the reason for not using the "url" that my url is not static

so I have to make some manipulation on the url before opening it,

Comment: any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate dynamically your button object that opens the URL, per your needs.

Comment: it should be a static , I am speaking on the persistent menu , it is initialized (once) in the first only , and can't be changed in run-time

Comment: @AhmedMohsen please update your original question to contain that the reason you want this because the persistent menu can only be set once.

Comment: Sorry but you did not mention anything about the persistent menu.